# Detect Sun Studio compiler and add platform libraries in CMakeList.txt?

Tags: cmake, solaris, sunstudio

Sun Studio 12.5 on Solaris 11.3. Solve one problem and move to the next... Building our project with CMake results the link error below.

I believe its a simple matter of detecting SunCC and adding `-lnsl -lsocket` to `LDLIBS`. However, the method to detect the SunCC compiler escapes me. I found an old post from 2006 that states (from [Error detecting sun studio compiler under linux](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake/2006-October/011667.html)):

> > I am trying to use the sun studio compiler under linux and I am having a
> >     terrible time getting past the cmake compiler tests.
>
> AFAIK no one has tried CMake with this compiler before.... CMake is invoking the compiler assuming that it accepts the flags other Linux compilers (such as GNU and Intel) accept... You'll have to setup a platform file to configure this compiler.

I tried to use `SunPro` from [CMake Compiler IDs](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html), but it results in the same error shown below.

```
if(SunPro)
    target_link_libraries(cryptopp-shared nsl socket)
    target_link_libraries(cryptest nsl socket)
endif()
```

My question is, how do I detect the Sun Studio compiler in CMakeList.txt? Or how do I detect Solaris?

---

```
/opt/developerstudio12.5/bin/CC   -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -D__SSE2__ -D__SSE3__ -D__SSSE3__
-D__SSE4_1__ -D__SSE4_2__ -D__AES__ -D__PCLMUL__ -D__RDRND__ -D__RDSEED__ -D__AVX__
-D__AVX2__ -D__BMI__ -D__BMI2__ -D__ADX__ -xarch=avx2_i
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/bench1.cpp.o CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/bench2.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/test.cpp.o CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/validat1.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/validat2.cpp.o CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/validat3.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/datatest.cpp.o CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/regtest.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/fipsalgt.cpp.o CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/dlltest.cpp.o
CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/fipstest.cpp.o  -o cryptest.exe  libcryptopp.a 

Undefined                       first referenced
 symbol                             in file
bind                                libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
recv                                libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
send                                libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
getservbyname                       libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
getsockname                         libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
accept                              libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
listen                              libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
gethostbyname                       libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
socket                              libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
setsockopt                          CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/test.cpp.o
connect                             libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
getpeername                         libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
inet_addr                           libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
shutdown                            libcryptopp.a(socketft.cpp.o)
ld: fatal: symbol referencing errors
gmake[2]: *** [cryptest.exe] Error 2
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/export/home/cryptopp-build'
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cryptest.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/export/home/cryptopp-build'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

---

Here's the CMakeList.tx file. It has not been checked in yet, so I have to dump it here:

```
$ cat CMakeLists.txt 
# Please ensure your changes or patch meets minimum requirements.
#   The minimum requirements are below, and they are 2.8.5. Please
#   do not check in something for 2.8.12. To test your changes,
#   please set up a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS system. Then, manually install
#   CMake 2.8.5 from http://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Released_Versions.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.5 FATAL_ERROR)

project(cryptopp)

set(cryptopp_VERSION_MAJOR 5)
set(cryptopp_VERSION_MINOR 6)
set(cryptopp_VERSION_PATCH 5)

include(GNUInstallDirs)
include(TestBigEndian)

#============================================================================
# Settable options
#============================================================================

option(BUILD_STATIC "Build static library" ON)
option(BUILD_SHARED "Build shared library" ON)
option(BUILD_TESTING "Build library tests" ON)
option(BUILD_DOCUMENTATION "Use Doxygen to create the HTML based API documentation" OFF)

option(DISABLE_ASM "Disable ASM" OFF)
option(DISABLE_SSSE3 "Disable SSSE3" OFF)
option(DISABLE_AESNI "Disable AES-NI" OFF)
set(CRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR "" CACHE PATH "Crypto++ test data directory")

#============================================================================
# Internal compiler options
#============================================================================

# Don't use RPATH's. The resulting binary could fail a security audit.
if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
  set(CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH 0)
endif()

set(LIB_VER ${cryptopp_VERSION_MAJOR}${cryptopp_VERSION_MINOR}${cryptopp_VERSION_PATCH})

if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Intel")
    add_definitions(-wd68 -wd186 -wd279 -wd327 -wd161 -wd3180)
endif()

# Endianess
TEST_BIG_ENDIAN(IS_BIG_ENDIAN)
if(IS_BIG_ENDIAN)
    add_definitions(-DIS_BIG_ENDIAN)
endif()

if(DISABLE_ASM)
    add_definitions(-DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_ASM)
endif()
if(DISABLE_SSSE3)
    add_definitions(-DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_SSSE3)
endif()
if(DISABLE_AESNI)
    add_definitions(-DCRYPTOPP_DISABLE_AESNI)
endif()
if(NOT CRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR STREQUAL "")
    add_definitions(-DCRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR="${CRYPTOPP_DATA_DIR}")
endif()

if(WINDOWS_STORE OR WINDOWS_PHONE)
    if("${CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION}" MATCHES "10\\.0.*")
        SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /D\"_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00\"" )
    endif()
    SET( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} /FI\"winapifamily.h\"" )
endif()

#============================================================================
# Sources & headers
#============================================================================

# Library headers
file(GLOB cryptopp_HEADERS *.h)

# Test sources. You can use the GNUmakefile to generate the list: `make sources`.
file(GLOB cryptopp_SOURCES_TEST bench1.cpp bench2.cpp test.cpp validat1.cpp validat2.cpp validat3.cpp adhoc.cpp datatest.cpp regtest.cpp fipsalgt.cpp dlltest.cpp fipstest.cpp)

# Library sources. You can use the GNUmakefile to generate the list: `make sources`.
file(GLOB cryptopp_SOURCES *.cpp)
list(REMOVE_ITEM cryptopp_SOURCES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cryptlib.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpu.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/pch.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/simple.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/winpipes.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cryptlib_bds.cpp
        ${cryptopp_SOURCES_TEST}
        )
set(cryptopp_SOURCES
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cryptlib.cpp
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cpu.cpp
        ${cryptopp_SOURCES}
        )

if(MINGW OR WIN32)
    list(APPEND cryptopp_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/winpipes.cpp)
endif()

if(MSVC AND NOT DISABLE_ASM)
    if(${CMAKE_GENERATOR} MATCHES ".*ARM")
        message(STATUS "Disabling ASM because ARM is specified as target platform.")
    else()
        if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
            list(APPEND cryptopp_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x64dll.asm)
            list(APPEND cryptopp_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x64masm.asm)
            set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x64dll.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/D_M_X64")
            set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x64masm.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/D_M_X64")
            set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rdrand.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/D_M_X64")
        else()
            set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x64dll.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/D_M_X86 /safeseh")
            set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/x64masm.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/D_M_X86 /safeseh")
            set_source_files_properties(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rdrand.asm PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "/D_M_X86 /safeseh")
        endif()
        list(APPEND cryptopp_SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/rdrand.asm)
        enable_language(ASM_MASM)
    endif()
endif()

#============================================================================
# Compile targets
#============================================================================

# Set global includes BEFORE adding any targets for legacy CMake versions
if(CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
    include_directories("${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}")
endif()

if(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.8)
    add_library(cryptopp-object OBJECT ${cryptopp_SOURCES})
endif()

if (BUILD_STATIC)
    if(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.8)
        add_library(cryptopp-static STATIC $<TARGET_OBJECTS:cryptopp-object>)
    else()
        add_library(cryptopp-static STATIC ${cryptopp_SOURCES})
    endif()

    if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
        target_include_directories(cryptopp-static PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/cryptopp>)
    endif()
endif()

if (BUILD_SHARED)
    if(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.8)
        add_library(cryptopp-shared SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:cryptopp-object>)
    else()
        add_library(cryptopp-shared SHARED ${cryptopp_SOURCES})
    endif()

    if (NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.12)
        target_include_directories(cryptopp-shared PUBLIC $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}> $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/cryptopp>)
    endif()
endif()

# Set PIC
if(CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P EQUAL 8)
    # Enables -fPIC on all 64-bit platforms
    if(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.9)    # POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE support
        set_target_properties(cryptopp-object PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE TRUE)
    elseif(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.8)    # Object library support
        get_target_property(flags_old cryptopp-object COMPILE_FLAGS)
        set_target_properties(cryptopp-object PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${flags_old} -fPIC")
    else()
        if (BUILD_STATIC)
            get_target_property(flags_old_static cryptopp-static COMPILE_FLAGS)
            if(NOT flags_old_static)
                set(flags_old_static "")
            endif()
            set_target_properties(cryptopp-static PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${flags_old_static} -fPIC")
        endif()
        if (BUILD_SHARED)
            get_target_property(flags_old_shared cryptopp-shared COMPILE_FLAGS)
            if(NOT flags_old_shared)
                set(flags_old_shared "")
            endif()
            set_target_properties(cryptopp-shared PROPERTIES COMPILE_FLAGS "${flags_old_shared} -fPIC")
        endif()
    endif()
endif()

# Set filenames for targets to be "cryptopp"
if(NOT MSVC)
    set(COMPAT_VERSION ${cryptopp_VERSION_MAJOR}.${cryptopp_VERSION_MINOR})

    if (BUILD_STATIC)
        set_target_properties(cryptopp-static
                PROPERTIES
                OUTPUT_NAME cryptopp)
    endif()
    if (BUILD_SHARED)
        set_target_properties(cryptopp-shared
                PROPERTIES
                SOVERSION ${COMPAT_VERSION}
                OUTPUT_NAME cryptopp)
    endif()
endif()

# Targets, compatible with Crypto++ GNUMakefile
if (BUILD_STATIC)
    add_custom_target(static)
    add_dependencies(static cryptopp-static)
endif()
if (BUILD_SHARED)
    add_custom_target(dynamic)
    add_dependencies(dynamic cryptopp-shared)
endif()

#============================================================================
# Third-party libraries
#============================================================================

if(WIN32)
    if (BUILD_STATIC)
        target_link_libraries(cryptopp-static ws2_32)
    endif()
    if (BUILD_SHARED)
        target_link_libraries(cryptopp-shared ws2_32)
    endif()
endif()

if(SunPro)
    target_link_libraries(cryptopp-shared nsl socket)
    target_link_libraries(cryptest nsl socket)
endif()

find_package(Threads)
if (BUILD_STATIC)
    target_link_libraries(cryptopp-static ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
endif()
if (BUILD_SHARED)
    target_link_libraries(cryptopp-shared ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
endif()

#============================================================================
# Tests
#============================================================================

enable_testing()
if(BUILD_TESTING)
    add_executable(cryptest ${cryptopp_SOURCES_TEST})
    target_link_libraries(cryptest cryptopp-static)

    # Setting "cryptest" binary name to "cryptest.exe"
    if(NOT WIN32)
        set_target_properties(cryptest PROPERTIES OUTPUT_NAME cryptest.exe)
    endif()
    if(NOT TARGET cryptest.exe)
        add_custom_target(cryptest.exe)
        add_dependencies(cryptest.exe cryptest)
    endif()

    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TestData DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})
    file(COPY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TestVectors DESTINATION ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR})

    add_test(NAME build_cryptest COMMAND "${CMAKE_COMMAND}" --build ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} --target cryptest)
    add_test(NAME cryptest COMMAND $<TARGET_FILE:cryptest> v)
    set_tests_properties(cryptest PROPERTIES DEPENDS build_cryptest)
endif()

#============================================================================
# Doxygen documentation
#============================================================================
if(BUILD_DOCUMENTATION)
    find_package(Doxygen REQUIRED)

    set(in_source_DOCS_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/html-docs")
    set(out_source_DOCS_DIR "${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/html-docs")

    add_custom_target(docs ALL
            COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} Doxyfile -d CRYPTOPP_DOXYGEN_PROCESSING
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
            SOURCES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile
            )

    if(NOT ${in_source_DOCS_DIR} STREQUAL ${out_source_DOCS_DIR})
        add_custom_command(
                TARGET docs POST_BUILD
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory "${in_source_DOCS_DIR}" "${out_source_DOCS_DIR}"
                COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove_directory "${in_source_DOCS_DIR}"
        )
    endif()
endif()

#============================================================================
# Install
#============================================================================
set(export_name "cryptopp-targets")

# Runtime package
if (BUILD_SHARED)
    install(
            TARGETS cryptopp-shared
            EXPORT ${export_name}
            DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
            RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR}
            LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
            ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR}
    )
endif()

# Development package
if (BUILD_STATIC)
    install(TARGETS cryptopp-static EXPORT ${export_name} DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR})
endif()
install(FILES ${cryptopp_HEADERS} DESTINATION include/cryptopp)

# CMake Package
if(NOT CMAKE_VERSION VERSION_LESS 2.8.8)    # CMakePackageConfigHelpers is supported from 2.8.8
    include(CMakePackageConfigHelpers)
    write_basic_package_version_file("${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cryptopp-config-version.cmake" VERSION ${cryptopp_VERSION_MAJOR}.${cryptopp_VERSION_MINOR}.${cryptopp_VERSION_PATCH} COMPATIBILITY SameMajorVersion)
    install(FILES cryptopp-config.cmake ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/cryptopp-config-version.cmake DESTINATION "lib/cmake/cryptopp")
    install(EXPORT ${export_name} DESTINATION "lib/cmake/cryptopp")
endif()

# Tests
if(BUILD_TESTING)
    install(TARGETS cryptest DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR})
    install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TestData DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/cryptopp)
    install(DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/TestVectors DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR}/cryptopp)
endif()


# Documentation
if(BUILD_DOCUMENTATION)
    install(DIRECTORY "${out_source_DOCS_DIR}" DESTINATION ${CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR})
endif()
```

Comment: Have you tried with the latest CMake 3.6? https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_ID.html

Comment: @usr1234567 - Yes, I'm using 3.6. And yes, I saw the page (it was cited). That's where I got the identifier `SunPro` from.

Comment: Your `CMakeLists.txt` script already checks compiler to be "Intel": `if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Intel")`. Checking compiler to be "SunPro" should be similar.

Comment: You don't want to check the compiler, you want to check the OS.   Building with the Studio compiler on Linux does not require -lnsl or -lsocket, but building with any compiler (Studio, gcc, clang) on Solaris does.

Comment: @alanc - OK, thanks. I was going to test that once I figure out how to do what I need to do. I kind of regret accepting the Cmake patches. They have been source of constant trouble. I've probably wasted a man-week on it even though others were supposed to be maintaining it (it was a condition of accepting the patches). I don't even use the tool...

Comment: @alanc - Yes, you were right. GCC encountered the problem too. Thanks.